# Python/tox, start a process before tests, shut it down when done

Tags: python, integration-testing, pytest, tox

I'm using [Tox](http://tox.testrun.org/) to check that the system I'm developing is behaving well when installed in a fresh environment (+ sanity checking the `setup.py` file). However, the system uses a `memcached` server, and ideally I'd like to spawn a new one for every `Tox` run.

Is there a preferred way to start programs before tests are run (and shut them down afterwards) or will I need to write a custom runner?

**Edit:** The test runner is `py.test`

Comment: You should probably do this in the _setup_ functions/methods of the actual unit testing framework (_py.test_, _nose_, _unittests_, ...) you are using with _tox_.

Comment: Good idea! Implementation was a breeze with `subprocess`. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Implementation note: `pytest_configure` and `pytest_unconfigure` in `conftest.py` was a good place to spawn/terminate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a task for `tox`. My recommendation is that you do this in the `setup` functions/methods of the actual unit testing framework (`py.test`, `nose`, `unittests`, ...) you are using with `tox`.

Original poster's comment:

> `pytest_configure` and `pytest_unconfigure` in `conftest.py` was a
>   good place to spawn/terminate.

Comment: pytest_configure/unconfigure are not the best for this since they will not work well with distributed testing (pytest-xdist plugin).  The py.test 2.3 release introduced the enhanced fixtures API to solve this problem, mark the fixture with @pytest.fixture(scope='session') to create a session-scoped fixture.

Answer (score 11):

To elaborate on flub's comment on the best way to do it with py.test, using its [fixture mechanism](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html).  Create a conftest.py file with this content:

```
# content of conftest.py

import pytest, subprocess

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def startmemcache(request):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(...)
    request.addfinalizer(proc.kill)
```

The "autouse" flag means that this fixture will be activated for each test run without requiring any references from tests. In practise, however, you might want to make the connection details to the subprocess available to your tests so that you don't have to work with magic port numbers.  You wouldn't use "autouse" then but rather return a fixture object for connecting to memcache, nicely encapsulating test configuration in one place (the fixture function).  See the docs for many more examples.

Comment: Much nicer than my initial implementation. I'll go for that.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use `paver` - http://paver.github.com/paver/ - for the spawning up and shutting down of your `memcached` server or any additional "miscellaneous system admin tasks" that you need to do during the execution of `setup.py` by `tox`.

Comment: but then you can't run the tests without tox anymore easily.  Doing it with the underlying test runner fits better i think.